# Print directly to a network printer without going to a print server

Tags: networking, printing, printer, network-printer

I'm experiencing very slow printing times (most of the time spooling). This is because my print server is located in another location which means my print jobs have to be sent to the print server and then back which is very and not to mention that I have a slow internet connection (2Mbps upload/download).

Is there a way to speed up the printing without having to set up a dedicated printer server in the office OR having to install drivers locally to every computer in the office.

Is there a way to send the print jobs directly to the local printer instead of to the print server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up a new printer there is the option to "Add printer by IP". You won't be able to get around installing drivers unless the printer supports IPP.

Comment: The printer does support IPP however reading the manual it requires drivers to be installed.http://manuals.konicaminolta.eu/bizhub-C554-C454-C364-C284-C224/EN/contents/id01-0167.html

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes the printer is connected via its internal network card - with a BizHub I can almost guarantee that. You need to find out the printer's IP address. If you don't know it, you can print a configuration page on the printer, which should tell you. The following prints the page on most BizHubs:

- Press the Utility/Counter button
- Select User Settings on the touch screen
- Select Printer Settings
- Select Print Reports
- Select Configuration Page
- Press Start

Once you have the IP address, you can install the printer as a **local** printer - if you have permissions to do that. On large corporate networks that is not guaranteed.

Go to Devices & Printers and Add a printer. Select "local printer". When asked for the port, create a new TCP/IP port with the IP address of the printer. When asked for the model, browse through the list, or select from the CD or downloaded drivers.